# Cross-Origin Failure with Express Node Server

Tags: firefox, curl, apache2, cors

My code works perfectly on localhost but when I get it uploaded to my Debian VPS server it will not fire.  However a cURL -H -origin request works perfectly...  I've tried everything PLEASE HELP!! lol

Here is my Firefox-Firebug error:::
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:10005/threadpreview. (Reason: CORS request failed).

---

This is really a HUGE problem for me.  I've tried just about EVERY Access-Control-Allow-Headers/Methods/Origin combination possible.  Truly at a loss.  I've also tried all the preflight requests.  It shouldn't need one but I've still tried to no avail.

Could it be server security?  I am working off of a VPS Debian Squeeze server.... Their firewall maybe?

This is my portfolio I need to get online so I can get myself employed.... sigh!  Please help and thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are accessing your webpage on a remote server you can't use local host.

You want to make the request against your vps IP address. Or domain name if you have it.

Calling local host on a browser client is going to request resources from the client computer as opposed to your server

Comment: I will give it a shot and post the results.  Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: I tried using both the domain and the IP address.  Both requests hang saying "pending" until finally failing minutes later....  So still not working unfortunately.

Comment: That sounds better than where you were.  Make sure you are still adding the port after the IP/Domain.  Can you confirm that the port is open using a tool like http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: OMG I FEEL LIKE AN IDIOT BUT YOU FINALLY SOLVED MY PROBLEM THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH.  TURNS OUT THE PORT WAS BLOCKED!!!!  Wow i don't care I'm just SOOO GLAD IT"S EFFING WORKING!!  Thank you everyone who contributed.  Much Love!!!!!!

Comment: SOLVED:  turns out if was BOTH a combination of having the port blocked (doh!) AND the prefetch headers!!  Thank you so much for everyone who helped me solve this.  I should have posted my problem a month ago.  TY SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: SOLVED: turns out if was BOTH a combination of having the port blocked (doh!) AND the prefetch headers!! Thank you so much for everyone who helped me solve this. I should have posted my problem a month ago. TY SO MUCH!!!!